# Best practices interfacing to device with Python's asyncio and pyserial-asyncio

Tags: python, pyserial, python-asyncio

I have written a Python package to read from and write to a serial device that uses short telegrams to communicate with sensors and actors. My classes include one to model the transceiver (it establishes the serial connection using serial.aio.create_serial_connection) and one for the telegram protocol based on asyncio.Protocol. I also have a bunch of classes for the different types of telegrams and devices.

While this all works, the device model and the protocol don't look very pythonic to me. Are there any tutorials or examples demonstrating best practices of how to do something like this?

Comment: i need python async serial library too. put it on github. i will help with it

Comment: thanks eri, but I'd rather not do that until my code looks a little better :-)

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/changyuheng/aioserial

Comment: Thanks, your package looks like it might help with the lower interface level. What I'm really looking for is a blueprint for a server that manages asynchronous devices and handles the connections of multiple clients.

Comment: Hi @maf, actually pyserial-asyncio is on a lower level comparing to aioserial.